# Problems when using groupby, how to calculate increase after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

#### A small sample of my data:

```
pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00')},
 'customer_nr': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 2},
 'product_nr': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1},
 'age': {0: 32.0, 1: 32.0, 2: 32.0, 3: 32.0, 4: 32.0, 5: 37.0},
 'gender': {0: 'M', 1: 'M', 2: 'M', 3: 'M', 4: 'M', 5: 'M'},
 'age_group': {0: '25-34',
  1: '25-34',
  2: '25-34',
  3: '25-34',
  4: '25-34',
  5: '35-44'}} )
```

#### Then I want to re-group like this:

`df.groupby(['date','product_nr','age_group']).age.count().unstack()`
Which looks like:

|  | age_group | 25-34 | 35-34 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **date** | **product_nr** |  |  |
| **2021-08-01** | **1** | 1 | NaN |
|  | **2** | 1 | NaN |
|  | **3** | 1 | NaN |
| **2022-08-01** | **1** | NaN | 1 |
|  | **2** | 2 | NaN |

#### Next step (?)

The next thing I want to do is to calculate how many percent product sales has increased from the first date to the second date, for each age_group. However, when I'm using groupby like this I find the new dataframe to be hard to work with.

#### Desired result:

| product_nr | 25-34 | 35-44 | 45-54 | 55-64 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x% | x% | x% | x% |
| 2 | x% | x% | x% | x% |
| 3 | x% | x% | x% | x% |

PS, the original data-set consists of significantly more products and customers.
I should also mention that there are not as many product_nr for both years and they are not arranged in the same order.

Comment: to be sure, you have only 2 dates in your real data?

Comment: Yes, I only selected two dates to look at the yearly increase.

Comment: When values in one or both of the dates is NaN, what should be percentage increase?

Comment: optimally I would leave that percentage as NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = df.groupby(['date','product_nr','age_group']).age.count().unstack()
```

Apply percentage change grouping on product_nr:(This code works also if you have multiple dates)

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
for group,df in t.groupby('product_nr'):
    temp = ((df/df.shift(1))-1)*100
    output = pd.concat([output,temp])
output.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

output:

```
age_group       date  product_nr  25-34  35-44
0         2021-08-01           1    NaN    NaN
1         2022-08-01           1    NaN    NaN
2         2021-08-01           2    NaN    NaN
3         2022-08-01           2  100.0    NaN
4         2021-08-01           3    NaN    NaN
```

Get the output for the date needed:

```
output[output['date'] == '2022-08-01']
```

Final output:

```
age_group       date  product_nr  25-34  35-44
1         2022-08-01           1    NaN    NaN
3         2022-08-01           2  100.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save that new grouped df and fill the nans in it with the fillna method.

```
df_group = df.groupby(['date','product_nr','age_group']).age.count().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Then you can save 2022 and 2021 data to new variables

```
df_2022 = df_group.loc["2022-08-01"]
df_2021 = df_group.loc["2021-08-01"]
```

And subtract them from eachother and divide by original to get percentage difference.

```
(df_2022 - df_2021).divide(df_2021)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Hmm (df_2022 - df_2021) only gives me NaN values.

Comment: Also, I should mention that there are not as many product_nr for both years and they don't display in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

use Groupby.apply with Series.pct change

df['pct_ch']=(df.groupby(columns)[age.count].apply(pd.series.pct_change)+1)

Comment: I wrote `(df.groupby(['date','product_nr','age_group']).age.count().apply(pd.series.pct_change)+1)` but got a error message : _AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series'_

Comment: If I write like your formatting : `(df.groupby(['date','product_nr','age_group'])[age.count].apply(pd.series.pct_change)+1)` _i get the error : NameError: name 'age' is not defined_